# java replaceAll and '+' match

Tags: java, regex

I have some code setup to remove extra spaces in between the words of a title

```
String formattedString = unformattedString.replaceAll(" +"," ");
```

My understanding of this type of regex is that it will match as many spaces as possible before stopping. However, my strings that are coming out are not changing in any way. Is it possible that it's only matching one space at a time, and then replacing that with a space? Is there something to the replaceAll method, since it's doing multiple matches, that would alter the way this type of match would work here?

Comment: It should work, but make sure you don't have other whitespaces.

Comment: Can you post more of the code?

Comment: My apologies guys; turns out I had the replace inside the catch of a try/catch and I jumped to conclusion about the regex too soon, where in reality my code just wasn't reaching the catch.

Comment: I can? It's telling me that I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach might be to use `"\\s+"` to match runs of all possible whitespace characters.

EDIT

Another approach might be to extract all matches for `"\\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\b"` and then join them using a space which would allow you to remove everything except for valid words and numbers.

If you need to preserve punctuation, use `"(\\S+)"` which will capture all runs of non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you string is spaces and not tabs? The following is a bit more "aggressive" on whitespace.

```
String formattedString = unformattedString.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

all responses should work.

Both:

```
String formattedString = unformattedString.replaceAll(" +"," ");
```

or

```
String formattedString = unformattedString.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

Maybe your **unformattedString** is a multiline expression. In that case you can instantiate an Pattern object

```
String unformattedString = "  Hello \n\r\n\r\n\r     World";
Pattern manySpacesPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+",Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher formatMatcher = manySpacesPattern.matcher(unformattedString);
String formattedString = formatMatcher.replaceAll(" ");
System.out.println(unformattedString.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

Or maybe unformattedString have special characters in that case you can play with Pattern flags en compile method.
Examples:

```
Pattern.compile("\\s+",Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
```

or

```
Pattern.compile("\\s+",Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```